# Live Text Recognition (OCR)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, tesseract

I was wondering if it is possible to operate OCR on an iPhone live camera mode without snapping a photo? The alphanumeric text is following a predictable or sometimes fixed combination (something like serial number).

I've tried OpenCV and Tesseract but I couldn't figure it out the way to have have some image processing on the live camera feed.

I just don't know the part that I have to recognise the text that I am expecting! Is there any other libraries that I can use to do this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with TesseractOCR and using `AVCaptureSession`.

```
@interface YourClass()
{
    BOOL canScanFrame;
    BOOL isScanning;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

@end

@implementation YourClass
//...
- (void)prepareToScan
{
    //Prepare capture session, preview layer and so on
    //...

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicked) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
{
    if (canScanFrame) {
        canScanFrame = NO;

        CGImageRef imageRef = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        [self.scanner setImage:image];

        isScanning = YES;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"scan start");
            [self.scanner recognize];
            NSLog(@"scan stop");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                isScanning = NO;
                NSString *text = [self.scanner recognizedText];
                //do something with text                     
            });
        });
    }
}

- (CGImageRef) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer // Create a CGImageRef from sample buffer data
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);        // Lock the image buffer

    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);   // Get information of the image
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    return newImage;
}
- (void)timerTicked
{
    if (!isScanning) {
        canScanFrame = YES;
    }
}
```

@end

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works. What do you suggest to minimize the cpu usage and have better accuracy? Do you suggest to crop the image on particular rect before sending to tesseract or use `tesseract.rect` ?

Comment: Yes it will help. Also try to make the image greyscale before sending it to tesseract, that will increase the recognition accuracy.

Comment: @arturdev where is self.scanner  defined?

Comment: @iajnr You can define it under the timer.

Comment: @arturdev     self.scanner = [[G8Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng+ita"]; is ok?

Comment: @arturdev any link(github maybe) with running code in objective c would help!